# Admob SMART_BANNER in android is not working when orientation is in Landscape mode

Tags: android, admob, smartbanner

I am using Admob SMART_BANNER in my android app. The app is showing when device is in portrait mode. But if the device orientation is in landscape mode then the add is not showing. I know banner add is not shown if there is not enough space to display an add. But in my case it seems to have enough space to display an add. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml file in values folder:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Banner Example</string>

    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>

</resources>
```

Java code:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder`enter code here`()
                .addTestDevice(uid)
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: can you post error and warning??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load adsize based on the devices' screen resolutions:

```
 AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;  

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();  
    double density = dm.density * 160;
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);   
    if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
        adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
    } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
        adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
    } else { // > 320 X 50
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
    }

   AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
     mAdView.setAdUnitId(yourAdUnitHere); 
     mAdView.setAdSize(adSize);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: smart_banner is used just to initialize adSize. Could have used adSize = null;

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to the original question, but I wanted to share my solution to a case of **SMART_BANNER** not working.

I found that in my case that SMART_BANNER wants to take the **entire width** of the screen regardless of the orientation - landscape or portrait.  I put the AdView at the bottom. If it is in a column that takes 80% of the width of the screen, it will neither show nor complain (i.e. not invoke onAdFailedToLoad).  It simply hides. Once it occupies the entire width, the ad shows without any problem.

Comment: adview width is set to match_parent and same for wrapper of this view, and still doesn't work, only test ad works

Answer (score 0):

```
try this below code

private void showBannerAd()
{
    AdView adView = new AdView(HomeActivity.this);
    //cal method to show banner add

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
    Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    }
    else
    {
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    }

    adView.setAdUnitId("AD_ID");
    AdRequest adRequest = new
     AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Secure.getString(getContentResolver()  
    ,Secure.ANDROID_ID)).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my app got crushed when I tried this code.

Comment: This code also gets crashed and block the logcat errors. If above code is not used my original code generates the following logcat:

Comment: 08-13 15:58:44.690    9803-9881/com.w3dreamers.bannerexample E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
08-13 15:58:44.690    9803-9881/com.w3dreamers.bannerexample E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
08-13 15:58:44.700    9803-9881/com.w3dreamers.bannerexample E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0

Comment: @KalaBabu it can't block your logcat errors what are you talking about? xD just choose no filters in Logcat window if you don't see all logs after one of your activities was crashed and app returned to first activity of your app..